# Why JavaScript like “owl.carousel” does not work in Odoo 10 web template?

Tags: javascript, odoo, owl-carousel, odoo-10

I am migrating a template from odoo 8 to Odoo 10 and using "owl.carousel" and other JS, and none of them work.

I want to know if the JS API changed? If so, how can an absolute newbe in JS learn how to fix the script..

This is the log console I get :

```
    unreachable code after return statement  web.assets_backend.js:3538:266
```

```js
/* /web_kanban/static/src/js/compatibility.js defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend' */
odoo.define('web_kanban.compatibility',function(require){"use strict";var kanban_widgets=require('web_kanban.widgets');var KanbanRecord=require('web_kanban.Record');var KanbanColumn=require('web_kanban.Column');var KanbanView=require('web_kanban.KanbanView');return;openerp=window.openerp||{};openerp.web_kanban=openerp.web_kanban||{};openerp.web_kanban.AbstractField=kanban_widgets.AbstractField;openerp.web_kanban.KanbanGroup=KanbanColumn;openerp.web_kanban.KanbanRecord=KanbanRecord;openerp.web_kanban.KanbanView=KanbanView;});;
```

```
    aucun élément trouvé  qweb:1:1
    TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function  web.assets_frontend.js:41:30
```

```js
/* <inline asset> defined in bundle 'web.assets_frontend' */
$(document).ready(function(){$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({loop:true,margin:10,nav:true,autoPlay:1000,responsive:{0:{items:1},600:{items:3},1000:{items:5}}})});
```

This is a test code that I included into my odoo Module:

```
    <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
            <!-- JS -->
            <script src="/my_theme/static/src/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
            <script src="/my_theme/static/src/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
            <script src="/my_theme/static/src/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_theme/static/src/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_theme/static/src/js/mousescroll.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_theme/static/src/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_theme/static/src/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_theme/static/src/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_theme/static/src/js/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_theme/static/src/js/wow.min.js"></script>
        </xpath>
```

Comment: could you elaborate on what you've done to debug? What does the console say? do you have access to error logs? is anything showing up?

Comment: @DanielC This is what I get from the console

Comment: How is your code related to the html? I see the jquery and owl-carousel script tags but I don't see where your custom code is implemented

Comment: @DanielC , the links and scripts goes to odoo head section, the div goes into a snippets. I wrote it like just to test the code. here it works fine, but when add the snippet to my web page, the page stays blank

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the OwnCarousel plugin exists on v10? I can see that some of my custom modules include the js library but I do not see it in either v8 or v10 of Odoo. Possibly you mean [Carousel](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp)?

If you indeed want to use OwlCarousel (which to me this seems to be the case) you have to download the library and include it in your static folder of your module for I do not think Odoo includes it.

Comment: Yes, I want to use OwlCarousel, I have dowloaded the library from [OwlCarousel2](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/), and included them inside `assets_frontend`, but nothing happen. Can't even see the images that I have in the div

Comment: How have you included the library on `assets_frontend`? Please paste the xml file

Comment: I have just added the code I had in assets_frontend. sorry for being late